# Pandas: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: pandas

Im getting this error message

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6+3'
```

Code

```
df['bedroom'] = df['bedroom'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the rows in the column bedroom has a value of '6+3' which is not possible to directly convert to int. you can do something like, df["bedroom"].replace("6+3", 9) and then cast it as int.